# How to write data to CSV file with string delimiter in Go

Tags: csv, go

I'm using "encoding/csv" csv.Writer to deal with csv output

How can I write data to CSV file with string delimiter like "|-|"

csv.Writer can only use single char as delimiter since Writer.Comma is defined as int32,
string delimiter is not supported

Comment: You cannot with the `encoding/csv` package, as it takes a single rune character (int32) as a delimiter. The string you have can/will contain more than 1

Comment: What have you tried? Please check the help section for more details on how to ask a question on this site. Questions are expected to show research efforts on your part, a minimal code example to reproduce/show what you've done, and a description of the desired behaviour/output. At the moment, this looks like a code-generation request

Comment: Go tries to follow RFC 4180, which a) is only a recommendation, not a standard; b) as far as I can tell, [doesn't expressly forbid multi-char delimiters](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180#section-2).  Still, I've never seen a CSV writer that will generate multi-char delimiters, and I suspect most CSV readers cannot be configured to parse multi-char delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

For using '|-|' as a delimiter you have to write your own custom write function. I have tried this code below and got the output like this:

*package main

```
import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type CustomCSVWriter struct {
    Writer    *csv.Writer
    Delimiter string
}

func NewCustomCSVWriter(w *csv.Writer, delimiter string) *CustomCSVWriter {
    return &CustomCSVWriter{
        Writer:    w,
        Delimiter: delimiter,
    }
}

func (c *CustomCSVWriter) Write(record []string) error {
    // Join the fields using the custom delimiter
    joinedRecord := strings.Join(record, c.Delimiter)

    // Write the joined record to the CSV writer
    return c.Writer.Write([]string{joinedRecord})
}

func main() {
    file, err := os.Create("output.csv")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error creating file:", err)
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()

    writer := csv.NewWriter(file)

    // Set the custom delimiter
    customDelimiter := "|-|"
    customWriter := NewCustomCSVWriter(writer, customDelimiter)

    data := [][]string{
        {"Alice", "25", "New York"},
        {"Bob", "30", "San Francisco"},
        {"Charlie", "28", "Chicago"},
    }

    for _, record := range data {
        if err := customWriter.Write(record); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error writing record:", err)
            return
        }
    }

    customWriter.Writer.Flush()

    if err := customWriter.Writer.Error(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error flushing CSV writer:", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("CSV data written to output.csv")
}*
```

I hope this was what you were asking for.

```
Alice|-|25|-|New York
Bob|-|30|-|San Francisco
Charlie|-|28|-|Chicago
```